# Scala style: constant map vs pattern matching

Tags: scala

I need to declare a constant mapping in scala, and wounder what would be the proper way to do that. 
The Java way is

```
private static final String[] numbers = {"zero","one","two","three"}  //Java
val numbers = Array("zero","one","two","three")  //Scala
val numbers = collection.immutable.HashMap(0 -> "zero", 1 -> "one", 2 => "two")  //Scala maps
```

Another way to do that in Scala is

```
 def array(i: Int) = i match {
   case 0 => "zero"
   case 1 => "one"
   case 2 => "two"
}
```

Is there a standard/recommended way to do it in Scala?

Answer (score 2):

Map provides features that a plain function does not. You can enumerate/scan/traverse/filter existing keys and values for example. Map/reduce/transform etc. (You can have a default value or generate an error on missing keys too, despite what the other answer suggests).

If you don't need any of that, there isn't much difference ... except, if the number of entries is fairly large, access to `Map` would generally be faster than evaluating the static pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. It depends on the purpose. Here's a version that generates the keys:

```
List("zero", "one", "two", "three").zipWithIndex.map(_.swap).toMap
```

(still a Map, assuming you can use the index)

I've seen both approaches used depending on the context.

If you need to serialize the mapping or pass it around or keep different versions of it, a Map would be better.

Otherwise, pattern matching might be better.

Comment: Your code generates the Map the other way about (String->Int). OP wants Int->String.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul You're right, I missed that. I updated the code to correct that.